# Application Layout

Tags: iphone, authentication

my application's layout is:

- Tab controller
  --> UIViewController1
  --> UIViewController2
  --> UIViewController3

I need a Login Screen before that, so I show a popup with "presentModalViewController" in the "didFinishLaunching" in app delegate.

But I want a login screen with a nav controller, this:

Login screen:

--> Select REGISTER or LOGIN

-> if REGISTER --> show view for register
-> if LOGIN --> show view for login

So I suppose I need a NavigationController, it's right?

I've readed many questions and one suggest me to create a layout like this:

- Navigation Controller
  --> Login Screen (with REGISTER or LOGIN) ---> register or login view ---> close view and show tabbar

Which between these ways is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the navigation controller when they go into the registration section. This would allow the user to step back out after they go in and also allows for some flexibility if your registration process ever needs to be made into multiple steps.

Another suggestion is that you should put the actual log-in form on the first view. This way users that have already registered with you will not have to perform 2 steps just to log-in.

Login Screen

1. Login Form
2. Register Button -> Register Views

Comment: I see Foursquare app have two buttons on the first view: JOIN NOW and LOGIN. But an user already registered doesn't must insert each times login informations. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to log the user in without requiring them to enter their authentication?

Comment: If the user has already log in into application yes, of course. I need use plist?

Comment: Each authentication application will be a little different depending on what is required for the process. If you want to log the user in automatically you will need to use some sort of storage mechanism to hold the user or device's authentication information. Either a plist, sqllite, etc. would work just fine.  Also, since it appears that you aren't requiring the user to enter any auth info than your layout seems to make sense to me.

Comment: Did you get everything figured out?